# Spring scheduler not getting triggered

Tags: spring-mvc, triggers, scheduler

I have a spring (4.2) based mvc gui web application. I am trying to add the spring based scheduler to run a cron job. When I deploy the application to the server, the scheduler does not trigger. However when I launch the web application, the scheduler gets trigger. Is there a have the scheduler triggered independent of the web application? Am I missing something? Any idea how to have this cron job method triggered independent of launching the web application? I am using the following.

Websphere application server 8.5
Spring 4.2

-servlet.xml file content

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.suraj.springmvc.controller" />
<task:annotation-driven />

<bean id="demoServiceBasicUsageCron"  
    class="com.suraj.springmvc.timer.CronJob"></bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Scheduler class

```
import java.util.Date;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;

@EnableScheduling
public class CronJob {
    @Scheduled(cron="0 0/2 * * * ?")
    public void demoService() {
        System.out.println("Method executed at every 2 minutes. Current time is :: " + new Date());
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need `@EnableScheduling` when you already have `<task:annotation-driven />` in xml config. Try this : Remove bean def `<bean id="demoServiceBasicUsageCron"...>` and replace `@EnableScheduling` with `@Service`.

Comment: I had missed to add the ContextLoaderListener in the web.xml. Now the spring scheduler is getting launched even without having to launch the web application